# how effective is transfer learning? keeping only two specific output features without resetting features

Tags: pytorch, resnet

**I want to keep only two specific output features without resetting features.**
Resetting features would lose the pre-trained weights.
For example, I don't want to do...

```
# https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html?highlight=transfer%20learning%20ant%20bees

model_ft = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)
```

[Here is code (following the transfer learning tutorial on Pytorch)](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html)

I want to do this to see how effective transfer learning is.
Even without transfer learning, a model might be effective. Removing 998 out of 1000 categories and leaving only two categories, ant and bee, could be a great categorical model since you are left with only two choices.

I do not want to re-train the model, I want to use the weights as it is, otherwise, it will be the same as transfer learning.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly try this. You can reduce the model output to just the two logits you want to compare with:

```
                chosen_cats = torch.Tensor([ant_index, bee_index]).long()
                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                outputs = model(inputs)
                outputs = torch.index_select(output, 1, chosen_cats)
                _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
```

In this scenario, the preds will be 0 or 1, with 0 predicting ant and 1 predicting bee, so you will need to also modify your labels to reflect this.

Comment: hey wouldn't this re-training the model? ```with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):``` I do not want to train the model. Otherwise it would be the same as transfer learning.